¿Como mejorar esta consulta para que no repita registros?
Access
tabla_caja
id,monto,fecha,tipo

SELECT c.Monto as entrada, c1.Monto as salida 
FROM DineroCaja c, DineroCaja c1 
WHERE 
    (c.Fecha Between #28/04/2024 00:00:01# AND #28/04/2024 23:59:59# AND c.Tipo='entrada') 
AND (c1.Tipo='salida' AND c1.Fecha Between #28/04/2024 00:00:01# and #28/04/2024 23:59:59#) ;

necesito que muestre una columna entradas y otra salidas de un día especifico,
Gracias de antemano!!

Para evitar repeticiones puedes usar GROUP BY, poniendo allí la o las columnas que deben ser únicas, cosa que no aclaras en tu pregunta.

Es la misma tabla y queres una sola fila, no?

¿Como esperas tener una relación entre las entradas y las salidas para que aparezcan en la misma fila? Por ahora estás haciendo un producto cartesiano y necesitas una condición para relacionar las filas.

Ahora estas combinando cade entrada de 2024-04-28 con cada salida de 2024-04-28. Dices que tu consulta repita registros. Entonces hay más de una entrada y/o salida por un día en tu tabla. ¿Por qué es así? ¿Hay una entrada por caja? ¿Una entrada por hora? Es como dice Luis Cazares: Si hay múltiples entradas y salidas, hay que relacionarlas. Explícanos tu tabla. ¿Qué contiene exactamente? ¿Qué son las llaves únicas de tu tabla?

Por favor danos un ejemplo. Algunos registros de tu tabla de ese día y el resultado que expectas para esas filas.

pequeñas cosas: Un coma en un join es la sintaxis de los años ochenta. Hoy en día usamos INNER JOIN. ¿Contiene la hora la columna fecha? En este caso sería un mal nombre. Un Date/Time en MS Access tiene fracciones de segundos. Entonces pueden existir registros entre 23:59:59 y 00:00:00 que no recoges con tu consulta.
